# JavaScript innerHTML with substring

Tags: javascript, substring, innerhtml

trying to put several strings inside a parenthesis. Why doesn't this work with substring? Getting the error "Invalid left-hand side in assignment".

```
<div id="p1"></div>

document.getElementById("p1");
var item1 = "item1";
var item2 = "item2";
var item3 = "item3"

p1.innerHTML="( )";

p1.innerHTML.substring(1,1) = item1 + item2 + item3;
```

Result should be: (item1item2item3). What's the best approach to achive this?

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qua1ity/w457hq6n/1/

Thanks!

Comment: You must always *assign* to `p1.innerHTML` to update it, you are not doing so in the last line, so presumably `p1.innerHTML = p1.innerHTML.substring(0,1) + item1 ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you *must* keep your code (i.e. you cannot change anything about it), You could try:

`p1.innerHTML = p1.innerHTML.substring(0,1) + item1 + item2 + item3 + p1.innerHTML.substring(2,3);`

[See Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w457hq6n/2/)

Otherwise, the easiest would be to use @Toby's answer in here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/29655908/600486

Answer (score 0):

This is how substring works http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp

if you want to wrap some variables in parenthesis do like this

```
p1.innerHTML = "("+item1 + item2 + item3+")";
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
p1.innerHTML = p1.innerHTML.substring(0,1) + item1 + item2 + item3 + p1.innerHTML.substring(1,1);
```

This assumes the current value of `p1.innerHTML` is `()`

Comment: did you try this answer?

Comment: Edited it to fix the typo and slightly incorrect, sorry!